# how to check subscription id in PayPal valid by php

Tags: javascript, php, html, paypal

Dears

how to check subscription id in PayPal valid by php i am getting from PayPal script

```html
<div id="paypal-button-container"></div>
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=********************************************************************-************&vault=true" data-sdk-integration-source="button-factory"></script>
<script>
  paypal.Buttons({
      style: {
          shape: \'pill\',
          color: \'blue\',
          layout: \'vertical\',
          label: \'paypal\',
          
      },
      createSubscription: function(data, actions) {
        return actions.subscription.create({
          \'plan_id\': \'****************\'
        });
      },
      onApprove: function(data, actions) {
        alert(data.subscriptionID);
      }
  }).render(\'#paypal-button-container\');
```

where i am getting this **data.subscriptionID** i want php code to check this subscriptionID email and other detailes.

in conclusion i want to get the subscriber information from PayPal data base

Comment: What do you mean by check id? Do you want to check that it matches your id in the db?

Comment: i want to check user email and name whom did this subscriptionID payment from PayPal database

Answer (score 0):

The API call to get information about a subscription is: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/#subscriptions_get

You will need to use a [REST App](https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Fapplications) clientID and secret to obtain an access token, and then do the above API call. See PayPal's developer documentation for details.

You can use PHP's curl library for these HTTPS API calls.

Comment: can you please give php script to pass also authorisations token  ?

Comment: The access_token, once obtained, is a required header parameter for the above API call.  To obtain the access token you need to make an Oauth2 call. See PayPal's developer documentation for details: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/get-an-access-token-curl/